# Wiki Internal Server Error

Tags: ros, server, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I just created a new page on the wiki:
ros.org/wiki/Robots/AllegroHand

I am getting an internal server error. Could you please restore this page and let me know what I may have done to cause this?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52954/wiki-internal-server-error/) by [alexalspach](https://answers.ros.org/users/4012/alexalspach/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-01-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This line was causing problems:

```
{{attachment:AllegroHandPeace.png||align="right" width="100px"}}
```

I've corrected it to: (note the added comma)

```
{attachment:AllegroHandPeace.png||align="right",width="100px"}}
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2013-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1